# Laravel 4 update table with array of records

Tags: laravel-4

Just filled table with an array of records using:

```
Floorplan::insert($floorplanMappedArray);
```

Tried updating the table by simply swapping "insert" with "update":

```
Floorplan::update($floorplanMappedArray);
```

Error message I'm receiving:

"Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory.

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not 
be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context.
```

You can't call a method like `Class::method()` if the method is not declared as static.

You have two possibilities :

Declare the method as static or create an instance of `Floorplan` :

```
Class Floorplan {
    public static function update() {
        // code goes here
    }
}

Floorplan::update();
```

Or :

```
Class Floorplan {
    public function update() {
        // code goes here
    }
}

$floorPlan = new Floorplan();
$floorPlan->update();
```

Comment: Created a new instance of Floorplan, and the update method worked.